# Syntax sugar for SUM of many Columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which has some columns that I want to sum up per row. It looks like

```
ID  VALUE1  VALUE2 VALUE3     ...  VALUE34
============================
1   1       2       2
1   2       2       5
2   3       4       6
2   4       5       7
```

I know that to sum two columns I can do

```
SELECT  ID, SUM(VALUE1 + VALUE2)
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY ID
```

Is there any syntactic sugar or something that can help me sum all the **34** values without having to do `SUM(VALUE1 + VALUE2 + VALUE3 + ...)` ?

Comment: 34 columns you need to total, why?

Comment: I'd run a query to get your table names: 
`SELECT *
   FROM information_schema.columns
   WHERE table_schema = 'your_schema'
   AND table_name   = 'tableName';` and then use Excel to construct a query taking advantage of column interpolation. Not pretty, but it works.

Comment: @bluefeet each `player` can play in 34 `matchdays` and score some points, so the table has the player id and the points per `matchday`

Comment: I'm sorry @AvraamMavridis that sounds like a terrible table structure you're stuck with.

Comment: @bluefeet What would you propose? Do you think is better to merge this columns into a single `json` column or what do you think is the best in this case?

Comment: Without knowing the entire reason for it I'm going to be guessing. But it sounds like you need a table for the `player`, then a table for the `matchdays`, then a join table to connect the two with a value. You'd have multiple rows for each player instead of multiple columns.

Comment: @bluefeet I see. Thx!

Comment: I agree that you should rather fix your data model. Having numbered columns is almost always a sign of a non-normalized model

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, in general you are right, but if you know that the number of columns is fixed and not going to change, then why not. For example, I have a table that has (among other columns) 24 columns called `hour0`, `hour1`, ... `hour23`. Each of them is `bit`. I know that a day will always have 24 hours and I need to store information with 1 hour precision. In this question, if 34 is the fixed number of matches and all 34 entries must have a value (no nulls), then having 34 columns is fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot go with a better data model, what about making use of arrays?  This also will allow you to change the number of elements in your table without having to alter it:

```
create table tableName (
  id integer,
  valuez integer[]
)
```

The equivalent of your query would be:

```
select id, valuez[1] + valuez[2] + ... + valuez[34]
from tableName
```

But with an array you can unnest and sum:

```
with sums as (
  select id, unnest (valuez) as val
  from tableName
)
select id, sum (val)
from sums
group by id
```

This also simplifies null handling -- simply add `where val is not null` and you can avoid mass coalescing.